# GoogleSheets API v4 Python : Unable to re-order sheets in google spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I want to reorder a Sheet1 moving it from index 6 to index 0.

```
def rename_worksheet(spreadsheet_id,
                     sheet_id,
                     new_title,
                     credentials, index=0):
    service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

    requests = {
        "updateSheetProperties": {
            "properties": {
                "sheetId": sheet_id,
                "title": new_title,
                "index": index,
            },
            "fields": "title",
        }
    }

    body = {
        'requests': requests
    }

    service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()
```

But the sheet remains on It's old position. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

In your request body, by `"fields": "title"`, only the title is updated. In your case, please add `index` to `fields` as follows. By this, the title and index of the sheet are updated.

#### From:

```
"fields": "title",
```

#### To:

```
"fields": "title,index",
```